# Pasar un dato de un select a un div

Tags: angular

Quiero pasar un dato que no va en el value de mi select a un div.

Yo tengo en mi select muestro dos datos

```
0 - Hola
1 - Adios
```

Por ejemplo, en el value mando el 0 o el 1 según el que escoja. Entonces quiero que **al seleccionar por ejemplo 1 en un div que tengo aparezca Adios.**

```
<ng-select [searchable] [virtualScroll] name="filterIdentificador" [(ngModel)]='filterIdentificador'>
  <ng-option value="" selected>Mostrar todos los grupos</ng-option>
  <ng-option value="{{fgrupos.identificador_grupo}}" 
    *ngFor="let fgrupos of nombreGrupoIden">{{fgrupos.identificador_grupo}} - {{fgrupos.nombre_grupo}}</ng-option> 
</ng-select>
```

Aquí quiero mostrar fgrupos.nombre_grupo

```
<div *ngIf="filterIdentificador != null && filterIdentificador != ''" 
    class="col-md-12 grupo-name-edit">
  <span>{{filterIdentificador}}</span>
</div>
```

Al poner filterIdentificador me muestra el fgrupos.identificador_grupo

Muchas gracias

```
import { ComponentFactoryResolver, Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { PersonalService } from '../../services/personal.service';
import { GruposService } from '../../services/grupos.service';
import { Grupos } from '../../models/grupos'; 
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-grupos',
  templateUrl: './grupos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grupos.component.css']
})
export class GruposComponent implements OnInit {
  public nombreGrupo:string;
  public grupos:Grupos;
  public idetificador:string;
  public nombreGrupoIden:any;
  public nombreGrupoMostrar:string;

  constructor(
    private factory: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private _contactosService:ContactosService,
    private _personalsService:PersonalService,
    private _pacientesService:PacientesService,
    private _gruposService:GruposService,
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router,
    ) { 
    this.nombreGrupo = '';
    this.grupos = new Grupos(0,0,'',0,0,0,0);
  }

  filterIdentificador:string = "";


  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPersonals();
    this.getPacientes();
    this.getGrupoIdent();
    this.getGrupoPersonal();
    this.getGrupoPaciente();
    this.getGrupoContacto();
    this.getGrupoNombre();
    this.getContacto();
  }

  papelera = [];
  pacientesgrupouno = [];
  terapeutasgrupouno = [];
  contactosgrupouno = [];

  terapeutas = [];
  pacientes = [];
  contactos = [];

  saveGroup(){
    //console.log(this.grupo2);  
    console.log(this.pacientesgrupouno);
    //console.log(this.terapeutasgrupouno[0].id);
    console.log(this.nombreGrupo); 

    for (let i = 0; i < this.terapeutasgrupouno.length; i++) {
      this.grupos = new Grupos(0,0,'',0,0,0,0);
      this.grupos.codigo_personal = this.terapeutasgrupouno[i].id;
      this.grupos.nombre_grupo = this.nombreGrupo;
      this.grupos.baja=0;
      this.grupos.codigo_paciente=0;
      this.grupos.codigo_contacto=0;
      this.grupos.identificador_grupo=this.idetificador["id"];
      console.log(this.grupos);
      this.saveContactoE();
      this.getPersonals();
      this.getPacientes();
      this.getContacto();
      alert('SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n')
      //console.log(this.terapeutasgrupouno[i].id);
      //console.log(this.nombreGrupo);  
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < this.pacientesgrupouno.length; i++) {
      this.grupos = new Grupos(0,0,'',0,0,0,0);
      this.grupos.codigo_paciente=this.pacientesgrupouno[i].historia;
      this.grupos.nombre_grupo = this.nombreGrupo;
      this.grupos.baja=0;
      this.grupos.codigo_personal=0;
      this.grupos.codigo_contacto=0;
      this.grupos.identificador_grupo=this.idetificador["id"];
      this.saveContactoE();
      //console.log(this.pacientesgrupouno[i].historia);  
      //console.log(this.nombreGrupo);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < this.contactosgrupouno.length; i++) {
      this.grupos = new Grupos(0,0,'',0,0,0,0);
      this.grupos.codigo_contacto=this.contactosgrupouno[i].id;
      this.grupos.nombre_grupo = this.nombreGrupo;
      this.grupos.baja=0;
      this.grupos.codigo_personal=0;
      this.grupos.codigo_paciente=0;
      this.grupos.identificador_grupo=this.idetificador["id"];
      this.saveContactoE();
    }
    this.getGrupoIdent();
    this.pacientesgrupouno = [];
    this.terapeutasgrupouno = [];
    this.contactosgrupouno = [];
    this.nombreGrupo='';
    this.getGrupoPersonal();
    this.getGrupoPaciente();
    this.getGrupoContacto();
    this.getGrupoNombre();
  }

  getGrupoIdent(){
    this._gruposService.getGrupoIdentificador().subscribe(
        result => {
          if(result['code'] != 200) {
           //console.log(result);

          } else {
            this.idetificador = result["data"];
            console.log(this.idetificador["id"]);
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.log(<any>error);              
        }
      );
  }

  getGrupoNombre(){
    this._gruposService.getGrupoNombre().subscribe(
        result => {
          if(result['code'] != 200) {
           //console.log(result);

          } else {
            this.nombreGrupoIden = result["data"];
            console.log(this.nombreGrupoIden);
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.log(<any>error);        
        }
      );
  }   
}
```

He tenido que borrar parte del código por que no me deja añadir el componente entero, ahí es donde saco el nombre del grupo

Comment: No es que afecte al código, pero tienes una propiedad llamada `idetificador`, le falta una **n**

Comment: Es que le puse así ya en todos los sitios xd

Comment: Si usas Visual Studio Code puedes renombrar un identificador poniendo el cursor sobre el mismo y pulsando F2

Answer (score 2):

Es algo muy típico al usar Angular restringirse al uso "estándar" de los inputs o selects en HTML: guardamos como valor un tipo simple de datos. En tu caso estás guardando el campo `fgrupos.identificador_grupo`:

```
<ng-option value="{{fgrupos.identificador_grupo}}" <!-- AQUI -->
*ngFor="let fgrupos of nombreGrupoIden">{{fgrupos.identificador_grupo}} - {{fgrupos.nombre_grupo}}</ng-option>
```

Y eso es lo que tienes en tu modelo. Pero Angular no tiene esta limitación, podemos trabajar con objetos enteros como valor

Tienes una solución sencilla: guarda el objeto grupo como valor

```
<ng-option value="{{fgrupos}}" <!-- TODO EL OBJETO -->
*ngFor="let fgrupos of nombreGrupoIden">{{fgrupos.identificador_grupo}} - {{fgrupos.nombre_grupo}}</ng-option>
```

y usa ese valor en tu div

```
<div *ngIf="filterIdentificador != null && filterIdentificador.identificador_grupo != ''"
    class="col-md-12 grupo-name-edit">
  <span>{{filterIdentificador.nombre_grupo}}</span>
```

Comment: Hola @PabloLozano muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero si paso el objeto entero no me permite filtrar, ya que al yo poner en el value el numero de identificador solo me mostrara en una lista los datos que tienen ese identificador

Comment: Puedes modificar el filtro para que mire el atributo, mira el div que he usado en mi respuesta.

Comment: no consigo hacerlo, no me saca los valores

Comment: Me dice que fgrupos no está definido

Comment: Necesitaría ver el código de todo el componente para ver qué te falla

Comment: Por donde puedo pasartelo?

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y añadir el código

Comment: Listo, tuve que borrar parte del código para que me dejase editarlo